# 3 point SQL update query

Tags: sql, join

I have a bit of a monster update query that I can't quite fit into the one query without doing a server side loop or anything.

I want to update a master account table, with values from two other tables.  The master account has 4 columns, accountID, areaID, stockID and amount.  The first three columns are the primary key.

The two tables I want to update details from are almost identical, one is incoming orders and one is outgoing orders.  They both contain columns orderID, stockID and amount.  With the primary keys being orderID and stockID.

There is another table orders, which will have the areaID and accountID for the order that will need referencing to update the master account table.  So far I can get a select function that gets the details I want, I just don't know how to transfer it to an update statement.

```
SELECT a.*,o.orderID, SUM(io.amount) as in,SUM(oo.amount) as out
FROM account_stock AS a 
  INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.accountID = a.accountID AND o.areaID = a.areaID 
  LEFT JOIN incoming_orders AS io ON io.stockID = a.stockID AND io.orderID = o.orderID 
  LEFT JOIN outgoing_orders AS oo ON oo.stockID = a.stockID AND oo.orderID = o.orderID
GROUP BY a.stockID,a.accountID,a.areaID
```

I am just completely lost if it is possible to run an individual update query that will update the account_stock file with the sum totals of incoming and outgoing stock.

Any suggestions for table structure changes etc will be welcomed as I understand my SQL isn't too conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should create two columns in your master table that contain what you called "in" and "out" in your select statement. "In" is a reserved word however, so don't use that. I haven't renamed it in the example so it makes more sense to you. I have rewritten the statement to make it an update instead of a select.

```
update
    account_stock a,
    INNER JOIN orders AS o 
        ON o.accountID = a.accountID 
        AND o.areaID = a.areaID
    LEFT JOIN incoming_orders AS io 
        ON io.stockID = a.stockID 
        AND io.orderID = o.orderID
    LEFT JOIN outgoing_orders AS oo 
        ON oo.stockID = a.stockID 
        AND oo.orderID = o.orderID
set
    a.in=sum(io.amount),
    a.oo=sum(oo.amount)
```

As noted in the comments, this will cause MySQL to flip a biscuit as it doesn't like aggregate functions in an set fieldname=aggFunc() area.

The following code should hopefully work:

```
update
    account_stock f
set
    a.amount=(
    SELECT 
        SUM(io.amount)-SUM(oo.amount)
    FROM 
        account_stock AS a
        INNER JOIN orders AS o 
            ON o.accountID = a.accountID 
            AND o.areaID = a.areaID
        LEFT JOIN incoming_orders AS io 
            ON io.stockID = a.stockID 
            AND io.orderID = o.orderID
        LEFT JOIN outgoing_orders AS oo 
            ON oo.stockID = a.stockID 
            AND oo.orderID = o.orderID
    where
        f.stockid=a.stockid
        and f.accountid=a.accountid
        and f.areaid=a.areaid
    )
```

Comment: This does get me on the right road.  Is there no way I can say at the end there, a.amount = a.amount + sum(io.amount) - sum(oo.amount)?

Comment: Sorry, must have miunderstood the question. Yes, you certainly can do that, but unless you are deleting records from your tables, you probably won't need to specify a.amount=a.amount+ etc... a.amount=sum(io.amount)-sum(oo.amount) should do the trick. Basically, you will be generating a new snapshot based on your entire tables, so you probably won't need to retain the last value.

Comment: Ok yeah, i get what you mean.  The query structure works perfectly and I can see how I should adjust the table structures to be more efficeient.

Comment: Ack! I am having issues using SUM in my query... no doubt because I am using MySQL (INNODB structure).

Comment: If I take out the sum values, it should still update all the matching rows therefore giving me the sum correct?  So if I was to say a.amount = a.amount + io.amount - oo.amount it should give sum totals because it would run on every row matching the stockID, areaID and accountID??

Comment: Taking out the sum may well cause it to just update with the last value. I am trying to write the subqueries in MySQL for you. MySQL doesn't like aggregate functions within the set clause, but does accept subqueries with aggregates in them.